# Smoothly adjust ImageView size during rotation animation

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-studio, android-animation

We created an ImageView that has the rotating parts of a wind turbine, and applied a rotation animation to it, and then added a SeekBar (slider) that allows the user to change the size of the rotating blades.

We've tried a bunch of different workarounds, but all of them have problems. Here's our current SeekBarListener:

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        // ImageView handle
        final ImageView part_imageView = (ImageView) view_final.findViewById(R.id.part_imageView);

        // When progress changes, change size of blades
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            part_imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 300 + (2 * progress);
            part_imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 300 + (2 * progress);
            part_imageView.getAnimation().reset();


            seekBar_text.setText(part_name + " size : " + (progress + 1));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

and here is the associated animation xml (applied to part_imageView before the listener is enabled).

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">

    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:duration="4000" />

</set>
```

The first thing we tried was only changing the ImageView width and height in the onProgressChanged, but this didn't update the animation and it animated around an axis that was no longer at the center (my guess is that it converts the pivot point to a fixed location rather than continually calculating it).

Next, we tried to reset the pivot point with `part_imageView.setPivotX(50);`, with the same for Y, but this didn't appear to have any effect on the rotation, it was still rotating off-axis.

Next we tried just reapplying the animation, but this reset the rotation to its start point, which was undesirable and looked spastic.

Next, I tried what's currently in the onProgressChanged, calling `part_imageView.getAnimation().reset();` after changing the size. This kept the current place in rotation (good), but flashed an image of the blades at the start of their rotation for one frame (bad) every time the bar changed. Because the SeekBar is pretty continuous (100 settings), the image flashes nearly the entire time we're changing the size, which looks horrible.

What we'd like is to be able to slide the bar the smoothly change the size of the ImageView without disrupting the animation. Is there a better way to approach this or a quick fix?

Comment: use `RotateDrawable`: it uses dynamic pivot calculation when drawing (it is not fixed after resizing your ImageView)

Comment: I tried to use a RotateDrawable, but it's not rotating, just loading the drawable. Do you know how I would get it to animate?
I also tried using an animated-rotate but that was extremely choppy (about 8 frames/ rotation), but it otherwise behaved how I'd want it to.

Comment: you would need to use an ObjectAnimator with target object set to your drawable,  with "level" as a property and values between 0..10000

Comment: Ended up putting that all into an xml for essentially the same thing. Thanks a ton!

Comment: does it work smoothly now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!
Ended up using a property animation rather than a view animation, creating an objectAnimator in xml and applying the animation to the ImageView.

Here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:ordering="sequentially" >

    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:duration="4000"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="360"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

Thank you pskink :)